# Stop all threads if an error is detected in one of them

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to implement multi-threading into an app. The app needs to create a variable number of threads whilst passing variables across. I can easily create the threads, however I am trying to figure out a way to be able to stop all threads at once and if an error is caught in any one of these threads, stop all of them.

My current solution is to enclose the functions in a loop that checks if a boolean value is "True", in which case the thread carries on. If there is an error, I change the value to "False" and all the threads stop. Similarly if I want to stop the threads manually I can set the value to "false" from a function.

Is there a better solution to this, as the main issue is the threads must reach the end of the loop before they stop completely?

Comment: When you say "an error is caught," do you mean that it throws an exception in the thread, or your code merely detects some sort of error?

Comment: Both - they are in a try catch block as well as my own stuff to check for errors

Comment: There are no solutions that make this any easier.  Other than solutions that actually work, a Boolean is not thread-safe if you don't declare it volatile, which you can't do in VB.NET.  Focus on Task and CancellationToken instead.  And whenever you do threading, first make *one* work.  It gets exponentially harder the more you use.

Comment: System.Environment.Exit(exitCode).  That should stop all threads immediately, no problemo.

Answer (score 2):

Running the threads in a while True block should be fine.  Once its false, you could just iterate over the threads and call thread.abort() even though sometimes using abort isnt a good idea.  Using a list of threads could be helpful.  I dont know how you are creating your threads but this should be easy to understand.

```
Dim listThreads As List(Of Threading.Thread)
'create/instantiate your threads adding them to the collection something like the following
For i = 1 To numberofthreadsyouneed
    Dim tempThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread
    tempThread.Start()
    tempThread.Add(tempThread)
next
```

Instead of using a while block just do a Try catch. inside the catch iterate over the list to abort the threads

```
Catch ex As Exception
    For each Thread in listThreads
      Thread.Abort()
    Next
end Try
```

Comment: How about providing a bit more detail?  Perhaps a brief code sample?

Comment: If thread abort is not always a good idea could you suggest an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Simply aborting the threads is the quick and dirty way to do it.  If abruptly killing all the threads you were running is the desired result then it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this doesn't solve the issue of the thread not stopping immediately unless I check for boolean=false after every line of code

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim foo As New List(Of Threading.Thread)
    Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(stopRun, 0L)
    For x As Integer = 1 To 5 'start five threads
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf workerThrd)
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start()
        foo.Add(t) 'add to list
    Next
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) 'wait two seconds
    Threading.Interlocked.Increment(stopRun) 'signal stop
    For Each t As Threading.Thread In foo 'wait for each thread to stop
        t.Join()
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("fini")
End Sub

Dim stopRun As Long = 0L

Private Sub workerThrd()
    Do While Threading.Interlocked.Read(stopRun) = 0L
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) 'simulate work
    Loop
    Debug.WriteLine("end")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

is a pretty sweet thing called **Tasks** that they come out with a while back. It gives you a little more control over your threads

Hope this helps.